# AES_encrypt : A return value of type "char *" cannot be initialized with an expression of type "unsigned char [12]

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm very new with C++ Programs and have a few questions.

1. When I compile, I have this Error: how can I transform the enc_out?
   `A return value of type "char *" cannot be initialized with an expression of type "unsigned char [12]".`
2. The input String pStr, is a char(12) in reality, then here the output enc_out I suppose it will be a char 12 also?
3. Do I have to do something to clean the memory? Someone told me to be careful of memory leaks?

Code:

```
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
    
//  compile:    /usr/vacpp/bin/xlC_r -O -q64 -qtbtable=full pxEnAndDeCrypt.cpp -lcrypto -o pxEnAndDeCrypt.out
// 

char* pxEnAndDeCrypt(char* pStr)
{
    static const unsigned char key[] = {  0x07,0x01 , 0xbb, 0xcc,  0xff  };

    unsigned char enc_out[12];
    unsigned char dec_out[12];
 
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;

    AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
    AES_encrypt((const unsigned char *)pStr, enc_out, &enc_key);      

    return enc_out;
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is work out the difference between C#, C and C++, you are obviously very confused. This is not C#

Comment: It looks like you've used inappropriate tags. Is this C or C++? Coz it sure as heck isn't C#.

Comment: I think you're just missing the & in front of the enc_out in the call

Comment: Remember `char[12]` holds **11 characters**.

Comment: among other things your return type of  `pxEnAndDeCrypt()` is `char*` but what you are returning is `unsigned char*` , that is the main error, and thats local to `pxEnAndDeCrypt()`

Comment: how can I transform "unsigned char " to "char*" ?

Comment: `enc_out` is a local object, which gets destroyed at the end of a function. You cannot return a pointer to the local object, as that would cause a dangling pointer. There are many different solutions for this. It all depends on your program design.